# Force chart labels to remain inside frame

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

RS2008 - pie chart

I have 'outside' labels with lines pointing to the segment (although strangely this only appears to work in pdf output)

However (see pic below) the label is appearing outside the scope of the chart area

How can I force it to remain inside? (MinimumRelativePieSize is set to 70)

(pic below missing due to not being able to find an image host that isn't blocked by corp firewall)

Picture a pie chart of 25 slices, with radial lines that project through the sides.
The line from each slice then becomes horizontal, before disappearing outside.
(above actually fits tune of "Lucy in the Sky with Diamonds")

Comment: Hard to answer your question with no information about what kind of chart (flash?) and you'd better ask this question on their support forum, or mailing list. You've more chance to get the answer there

Comment: Well seeing as the top of the post has "RS2008" and all the tags state "reporting services" and I've put the type of chart as "pie chart", 
I'm guessing I mean a pie chart in Reporting Services 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set MinimumRelativePieSize to 50 and it seems to work ok.

I guess they need to implement a MaximumRelativePieSize property.